# Adding floating point/double numbers in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x87

I am trying to experiment with inline assembly, and I am trying to add decimal numbers (no, NOT integers) in inline assembly. Issue is, when I call the following function:

```
inline double ADD(double num1, double num2) {
  double res;
_asm{

    push eax; push the former state of eax onto stack
    mov eax, num1;
    add eax, num2;
    mov res, eax;
    pop eax; restore the former state of eax now that we are done   
     }  return res;}
```

The compiler complains of improper operand size at the inline assembly (ALL lines of assembly excluding the push and pop instruction lines). So I have to change to an integer type, such as unsigned long, and then it works, but of course only supports integer types; decimal results are rounded.

Is there any way to add in assembly that allows for decimal results like 8.4?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The answer to your question might depend upon the compiler you use. What compiler/IDE/OS do you use?

Comment: N.B. binary floating point numbers (`float`, `double`, etc) are not decimal floating point numbers are not real numbers (in the math sense).

Comment: visual c++ 2010 express is the IDE I use, with windows of course.

Comment: @delnan I really don't care that they are not technically decimal numbers "in the math sense". I just want to be able to compute an answer that is not rounded to an integer type; ex: 8 + 1.8 = 9.8, NOT 10.

Comment: Neither 1.8 nor 9.8 are representable exactly as a double.

Comment: What @FredOverflow cites is one of many reasons you *should* care (there are extensive resources on others, but they explain in depth and thus require a lot of math and/or bit fiddling knowledge to understand well, so let's leave it at that). Sadly, it checks out most of the time, but you *will* encounter "weird errors" in such calculations, so I thought I'd warn you. Just search SO to see hundred of examples - it's one of the most common questions.

Comment: Please don't `push eax`. That's the only register you don't need to save because it returns the result.

Comment: FYI, eax is 32 bits wide but doubles are 64 bits. That was never going to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't done x87 assembly in a decade, but it should be something like:

```
fld num1   ; load num1 and push it onto the fpu stack
fld num2   ; load num2 and push it onto the fpu stack
faddp      ; pop two numbers, add them, push sum on the stack
fstp res   ; pop sum from the stack and store it in res
```

Comment: what do those instructions mean? I only know basic assembly instructions.

Comment: I added comments for your convenience. You should probably read up on x87, it is a stack-machine (as opposed to the x86 which is a register-machine).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. That helped a lot, but however, it complains that faddp has been given an illegal number of operands. I changed it to fadd, and it worked! I can work with floating-point numbers now!!!!!! YAY! Thanks alot! :D

Comment: fadd will lead to an unbalanced stack, try these variants: `faddp st1,st0` `faddp st1,st` `faddp st(1),st(0)`

Comment: I did that last one you showed in place of fadd, and it shows the exact same results as fadd, so thats good, PLUS the fact it doesn't apparently harm the stack like fadd might :). Thanks Jen. Also, I see how they work, with st(num) referencing certain areas of the stack. Good learning experience for me :).

Answer (score 6):

The instruction you probably want is ADDSD, but I don't know for sure.

Here's the link to Intel's instruction set manuals. 
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html/

They used to mail you hard copies for free, but it looks like that's no longer true.

Comment: +1 for recommending SSE2 instead of the antique x87 instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You need a different set of instructions to manipulate floating point numbers. Here's an introduction that should help: [x86 Assembly: Floating Point](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Floating_Point)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
_asm{

movq xmm0,[num1]
addpd xmm0, [num2];
movq [res],xmm0
// sse2
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer, above, that you have to push the operands onto the FP stack and pop the result is correct.

However, the proximate cause of the "improper operand size" errors is that "extended" registers, "e__" (e.g. eax) are 32-bit and double-precision floating-point numbers are 64-bit.